# Angular push array items to new array

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have returned data from server like:

```
{
  user:{id: 1, ......},
  wishes:[
    {id: 3, ......},
    {id: 4, ......}
  ]
}
```

What I try to do is to push all items from `wishes` to an array named `products` but it returns undefined in view.

## Code

`controller`

```
products: any[] = [];
limit = 10;
loading: any;

async getProducts() {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait...',
      spinner: 'crescent',
      duration: 2000
    });

    await this.loading.present();

    this.wishlistService.getProducts().subscribe((res) => {
      for (let product of res['wishes']) {
        this.products.push(product);
      }
      this.hideLoading();
    });
  }

  private hideLoading() {
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
```

`HTML`

```
<ion-row padding *ngIf="products.length>0 else noItem">
  <ion-col size="6" class="prodCard" size-sm *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0:limit">
  //rest of html part
  </ion-col>
</-ion-row>
```

**PS**

with `console.log(res['wishes']);` I can get my wishes part but somehow in my loop code (above) it doesn't work *Maybe I placed it wrong*

Any idea?

Comment: print `typeof res['wishes']` and check whether its an array or what ?/ and have u tried by removing `| slice:0:limit` ?/

Comment: **1** `typeof res['wishes']` I place this in `console.log()`? **2** no that's for pagination it has nothing to do with returned data, if data exist it simply paginate them that's all.

Comment: First, check the **key name** is same as come from the response, Check it's in array form and also check array length.

Comment: can u create a repo and share I can help if I can check on my Pc :)

Comment: **ref** https://ibb.co/9T77vxq  **code** http://collabedit.com/f8wwx

Comment: @KishanOza a bit more logic to help you understand my data https://ibb.co/TB72tCB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your data the `product` is nested inside `wish` object so you can access it like this:

```
for (let wish of res['wishes']) {
    this.products.push(wish.product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use data.wishes in ngFor.

[StackBlitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okmrdk)

```
 data = {"user":{"id":1,"name":"user name"},"wishes":[{"id":11,"name":"some wish"},{"id":52,"name":"wish item"}]};

 <li *ngFor="let product of data.wishes">{{product.name}}</li>
```